# Change chapter and section color memoir class

Tags: color, memoir

I can't figure out how to change the colour of ALL the chapter and section headings. I have tried a lot of different things (see code). No matter what I do I can't change the colour of the started * Chapters and sections. Like so the colour of the `\appendixpage` and nomenclature doesn't change.

Bonus question: How do I change the `\appendixpage` to spell "Bilag" instead of "Appendices"?

Sorry for the long code but don't know what's relevant

My main code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\chapterstyle{madsen}% Chapter style
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Setting the output font
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{textpos} % positioning of textblocks on the page
\usepackage{graphicx} % includes graphics in document
\graphicspath{{gfx/}} % Path to graphics
\usepackage{ifthen} % provides ifthen structure
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage[intoc, refpage]{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}`

`\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=-0pt}`

`\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\item[\textbf{Symboler - Greek}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{L}}{\item[\textbf{Symboler - Latin}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Forkortelser}]}{}}}}`


`\newcommand{\myitem}{\item[\includegraphics{./gfx/item_bullet.png}]}`



`%------------
%------------
% BELOW IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED TO DO
%----------coloring chapters and sections
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{sectsty}
%\chapterfont{\color{blue}  % sets colour of chapters
%\sectionfont{\color{cyan}}  % sets colour of sections
%----------------------------------------`


`\usepackage{xcolor}
% define colors
\definecolor{sectioncolour}{RGB}{31,78,121}
\definecolor{chaptercolour}{RGB}{31,78,121}
\definecolor{subsectioncolour}{RGB}{31,78,121}`

`%\addtodef{\printchaptername}{\color{chaptercolour}}{} %Change chapter color
%\addtodef{\printsectionname}{\color{Red}}{} %Change chapter color
%\addtodef{\tocheadstart}{\color{red}}{} % If you want the whole TOC to be blue also
%\addtoiargdef{\printtoctitle}{\color{Green}}{} % If you just want the TOC title blue
%\setsechook{\color{Red!50!yellow}}`

`% This sets the colours in Tables of Contents
%\renewcommand*\cftchapterfont{\color{chaptercolour}}
%\renewcommand*\cftsectionfont{\color{sectioncolour}}
%\renewcommand*\cftsubsectionfont{\color{subsectioncolour}}`

`% set colours in chapters
\addtodef{\printchaptername}{\color{chaptercolour}}{}
%\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\Large\bfseries\color{chaptercolour}}
%\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\color{chaptercolour}}
%\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\color{chaptercolour}}`

`% Sets colours and style of sections and subsections
%\setchapheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\color{chaptercolou}}% Set \section style
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\color{sectioncolour}}% Set \section style
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\color{subsectioncolour}}% Set \subsection style`

`%---------
%---------`


`\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Forord}
\newpage
\vspace*{-2cm}
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\chapter{Intro}
\nomenclature[A]{BIM}{Building Information Modelling}
\nomenclature[A]{IPD}{Integrated Project Delivery}
\appendixpage
\chapter{Tomt appendix A}
\backmatter
\printnomenclature
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
%\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it on my own..
Wrote the following in my preamble

```
% REDEFINE CHAPTERS AND SECTIONS
\usepackage{xcolor}
% define colors
\definecolor{sectioncolour}{RGB}{23,85,142}
\definecolor{chaptercolour}{RGB}{23,85,142}
\definecolor{subsectioncolour}{RGB}{23,85,142}

\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\color{sectioncolour}}% Set \section style
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\color{subsectioncolour}}% Set \subsection style


\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\large\scshape\raggedleft\color{chaptercolour}}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\bfseries\color{chaptercolour}}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\raggedleft\color{chaptercolour}}
```